# I'm trying to implement a selection sort on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

The list contains a number of tuples with the first element of the tuple being a name and the second element being a rating.

```
Tuple = [('Bob', 123),('Sky', 234),('Sara', 156)]    
for i in range(0, len(Tuple)-1):

    smallest = i

    for j in range(i+1, len(Tuple)):

        if Tuple[j] < Tuple[smallest]:

                    smallest = j

    if smallest !=i:

        Tuple[i], Tuple[smallest] = Tuple[smallest] , Tuple[i]
print(Tuple)
```

This will sort the list in alphabetical order but I want it to be sorted by rating highest to lowest.

I've tried this:

```
for i in range(0, len(Tuple)-1):

    smallest = i[1]

    for j in range(i+1, len(Tuple)):

        if Tuple[j[1]] < Tuple[smallest]:

                    smallest = j

    if smallest !=i:

        Tuple[i], Tuple[smallest] = Tuple[smallest] , Tuple[i]
print(Tuple)
```

But I get an error saying "smallest = i[1] TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'

I don't know how else to do this or how I can change it to make it work.

Note: I need to write the code myself and not use any built in functions.

Comment: Do you need to write a sorting function yourself, or just to sort a tuple? You can use `sorted(Tuple, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: I need to write it myself

Comment: @BrendanLevine I changed my answer to include a solution without built-ins

Comment: @Signal Thanks so much it works, this is part of my final in my intro to programming class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your original list,

```
names_ratings = [("Bob", 123), ("Sky", 234), ("Sara", 156)]
```

You can use the python builtin `sorted`.

```
names_ratings_sorted = sorted(names_ratings, key=lambda tup: tup[1])

print(names_ratings_sorted)
```

**Output:**

```
[("Bob", 123), ("Sara", 156), ("Sky", 234)]
```

---

**Without builtins:**

Using the same original list,

```
names_ratings = [("Bob", 123), ("Sky", 234), ("Sara", 156)]
```

This works without using any built-ins.

```
names_ratings_sorted = []

while names_ratings:

    maximum = names_ratings[0]

    for name, rating in names_ratings:

        if rating > maximum[1]:

            maximum = (name, rating)

    name_ratings_sorted.append(maximum)
    names_ratings.remove(maximum)
```